# How is sign bit represented in a 32 bit machine

Tags: c, byte, bit

Lets say I work in a 32 bit machine. With reference to MSB (most significant bit) which is the sign bit, my question is how is it represented for this archietecture.

My understanding is that every byte has a sign value. So if this is the case then there would be four signed bits. Am I correct or missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: It depends: Is a byte signed or unsigned by default with your compiler?

Comment: Bytes don't have "signs". A byte is just a unit of data. It has no meaning beyond that.

Comment: See example of signed/unsigned interpretation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123014/what-is-the-deal-with-assigning-an-unsigned-variable-to-a-signed-value/11123205#11123205)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bytes are groups of bits. They don't have any inherent meaning, and neither do the bits that make them up. Meaning is only given if you e.g. *choose to interpret* these four bytes as a signed integer, and then the bits mean what they mean because the platform designers say so.

In practically all prevalent architectures, integers are represented using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). This means that:

1. There's only one sign bit for the whole value (not for every byte), but this is a *de facto* condition, simply because the platform designers *chose* to use two's complement -- not because there's something special about all MSBs in the universe.
2. There's no sign bit at all for unsigned values (obviously).

Answer (score 3):

The specific representation of integers in C is **not specified by the standard**. However, in practice, most (virtually all?) machines will use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation for negative numbers. Two's complement does not have a sign bit, *per se*, but the most significant bit of the integer will be 1 for negative numbers and 0 for nonnegative numbers,

Answer (score 0):

On most architecture your 32-bits signed integers are stored in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) : there is only one "sign bit" (which is not really one strictly speaking).

Answer (score 0):

If you're wrking with signed integers, then the compiler treats groups of bytes as an entire number, and that group has one sign bit. In C terminoligy: when you use `int16_t`, two bytes have one sign bit. For `int32_t`, four bytes have one. For `signed char`, each signed char (=byte) has a sign bit.