# Check if unsigned is less than zero

Tags: c

Playing with some sources found code like this:

```
void foo(unsigned int i)
{
 if(i<0)
     printf("Less then zero\n");
 else
     printf("greater or equ\n");
}

int main()
{
    int bar = -2;
    foo(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

I think there is no sense, but may be there some cases(security?) that makes this check sensable?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! You have strengthened my confidence. But someone wrote this. May be there some platforms or compilers which think another way?

Comment: There may be some slight variation of the exact values for signed/unsigned conversions depending on the size of an int on your system (see the answers linked to by jonnyGold and wap26). But all compilers will output executables that exhibit the same control flow behavior in this case. In other words-- no :) Whoever wrote this probably didn't notice that this control flow situation would occur (a bug) or else they were experimenting.

Comment: Seems like you're right.
I did some checks. gcc just removes any checks and write string:
`foo:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $24, %esp
        movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
        call    puts
        leave
        ret`

Clang generates check, but:
1. void foo(unsigned int i)
inline `foo+19: jae    0x804841f <foo+47>`
2. void foo(signed int i):
inline `foo+19: jge    0x804841f <foo+47>`

Answer (score 13):

An unsigned int cannot be less than 0 by definition. So, to more directly answer your question, you're right in thinking that this makes no sense. It is not a meaningful security item either unless you encounter something like a loop that accidently decrements a signed int past 0 and then casts it as an unsigned int for use as an index into an array and therefore indexes memory outside of the array.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe) sheds light on what happens when you cast from a negative-valued int to an unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

`i` will always be `>=0`because it is declared as `unsigned` and thus interpreted as an unsigned integer.
So your first test will always be false.

Your call `foo(bar)` actually converts an `int` into an `unsigned int`. This may be what confuses you. And "conversion" does not actually change the bytes/bits value of your integer, it is just a matter of formal typing and interpretation.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123014/what-is-the-deal-with-assigning-an-unsigned-variable-to-a-signed-value/11123205#11123205) for examples of signed/unsigned conversions.

Here is a simple example (the exact output depends on the number of bytes of an `unsigned int`on your system, for me it is 4 bytes).

Code:

```
printf("%u\n", (unsigned int) -2);
```

Output:

```
4294967294
```